# Sci-fi movie identification: on TV in early 2000s or earlier - cannibal alien family

Tags: story-identification, movie

So this has bothered me for ages, I have never been able to figure out what the movie was despite many attempts. When I was a kid (it was around New Years in either 2000/2001, or 2001/2002) my family was watching a movie on TV about aliens masquerading as humans in modern-day society who were secretly killing and eating people. The most prominent characters were the alien mom, who looked like a classic stepford wives homemaker with a beehive and sequined glasses; an attractive blonde teenage daughter, and a black guy who was involved with the family somehow (friend? neighbor? roommate? I'm not sure) and he began to realize that they were responsible for mysterious murders around town, when they couldn't properly explain where they got the odd-looking roast on the dinner table. I also remember that when the aliens got cut or stabbed, they bled thick metallic blue goo.

One of the reasons I have trouble identifying it is that my mom was just flipping through channels so we started watching in the middle of the movie, and then maybe 30 minutes into it she changed her mind and I never saw it again. I've been trying for years to identify this movie so I could finish watching it.

It probably aired on Sci-Fi channel, it that helps at all!

Comment: Mars Attacks? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/MarsAttacks

Comment: The Arrival? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6ST9dsDGRg

Comment: @Valorum - Does either of those really match? Neither seems to have alien protagonists who are unaware of being responsible for murders.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - The first one has aliens in beehive hairdos and the second one has aliens taking over bodies and masquerading as humans. Neither is an especially good match hence why I posted them as comments. If nothing else, perhaps it'll jog some extra memory cells.

Comment: It wasn't either of those, but I appreciate the comments! It had a much more serious tone than Mars Attacks.

Comment: [Meet the Applegates](http://www.imdb.com/video/screenplay/vi2844655897)?

Comment: Similar to it! I actually think I just figured it out from trying different google searches and it was most likely a 1997 TV movie called Alien Avengers / Welcome to Planet Earth. WOW I thought I was never going to find it!!!   What's the protocol for this site if someone ends up figuring out the answer to their own question?

Comment: @Valorum I guess my limited viewing of the movie made it seem more serious in tone than it actually was!

Comment: @Erica - Now you get to self-answer and reap the juicy rewards of having both the question and answer for people to upvote

Answer (score 7):

After trying a different pattern of google searches, I finally figured out what the movie was!  A 1997 TV movie called "Welcome to Planet Earth," also called "Alien Avengers," a dark comedy about an alien family who vacations to earth in order to hunt (and apparently eat) criminals; the black guy in the story is their landlord, who later becomes romantically involved with the daughter alien.

Now that I've identified the movie... It was probably on a channel like HBO rather than Sci-Fi, since it has graphic violence and sex. Probably a good thing my mom didn't let me watch it as a kid!